# How to move ipcMain.on calls outside the main.js file

Tags: javascript, electron, ipcrenderer, ipcmain

I am working on a project with Electron and React. I am going to be making multiple calls to the database via ipcMain and ipcRenderer so I moved the calls for ipcMain to another file(ipcMainHandler.js).

The challenge I am facing now is how to send responses back to the ipcRenderer. I am unable to access the mainWindow from within that file.

This is the code for my main file.

```
const url = require('url');

const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron');

let mainWindow;

function createWindow() {
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true,
      enableRemoteModule: true,
      preload: __dirname + '/preload.js'
    },
  });

  const startUrl =
    process.env.ELECTRON_START_URL ||
    url.format({
      pathname: path.join(__dirname, './build/index.html'),
      protocol: 'file:',
      slashes: true,
    });

  mainWindow.loadURL(startUrl);
  mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools();
  mainWindow.on('closed', function () {
    mainWindow = null;
  });
}

app.on('ready', createWindow);
app.on('window-all-closed', function () {
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
    app.quit();
  }
});
app.on('activate', function () {
  if (mainWindow === null) {
    createWindow();
  }
});

require('./src/server/helpers/ipcMainHandler.js');
```

The ipcMainHandler.js file

```
const { SIGNIN_REQUEST, SIGNIN_RESPONSE } = require('../../common/events.js');
const { ipcMain } = require('electron');

ipcMain.on(SIGNIN_REQUEST, (event, data) => {
  const user = AuthController.userSignin({ ...data });
});
```

**Things I have tried**

- Accessing the currentWindow from remote - throws a remote undefined error
- Adding the mainWindow to a global variable and trying to access it in the ipcHander. - This also returns an undefined message.

Answer (score 0):

This has been resolved. I used the event object to send the response from ipcMain.

```
ipcMain.on(SIGNIN_REQUEST, async (event, data) => {
  const user = await AuthController.userSignin({ ...data });
  event.sender.send(SIGNIN_RESPONSE, user);
});
```